# Cannot remove mistyped repository

Tags: updates, ppa, repository

I accidentally mistyped a ppa when adding it.

Instead of `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa` 
I used `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xmbc/ppa`

(x**mb**c instead of x**bm**c)

Now I get an error when I start up.

[image: Error]

When I try and use `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:team-xmbc/ppa` I get this: http://pastebin.com/ZsBi1F7L

This is on 15.04

Checking /etc/apt/sources.list.d there isn't an entry for this. http://pastebin.com/1RmYnmAD

Using `sudo ppa-purge ppa:team-xmbc/ppa` gives:

`Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: team-xmbc ppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: team-xmbc ppa`

Comment: Where is the difference between your commands?

Comment: xbmc vs xmbc . I basically mistyped. I've since added it and done what I wanted to. I tried to bold it but the stack syntax didn't seem to let me do it inside a code block.

Comment: Go into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and remove the file with the misspelled entry: `*xmbc*.list`

Comment: I checked that, there is only the correct one there.

Comment: I will test it immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is good, you can ignore the problem, that's a bug. Your command has caused no harm.

The "problem" was this, and that's ok in your case:

```
softwareproperties.ppa.PPAException: 'Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~team-xmbc: Not Found'
```

in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 119, in <module>
    shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 837, in shortcut_handler
    ret = factory(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 382, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 346, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 333, in get_ppa_info
    _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 292, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
    lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 87, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in _get_https_content_py3
    raise PPAException("Error reading %s: %s" % (lp_url, reason), e)
softwareproperties.ppa.PPAException: 'Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~team-xmbc: Not Found'
```

[Here is the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1453501).