# Installing Kodi, add apt-repository won't work

Tags: apt, ppa, touchscreen, kodi

I've been following the instructions to install Kodi on my Ubuntu built pi as per [the instructions here](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/07/kodi-15-isengard-has-been-released.html). However, when I get to the install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository pps:team-xmbc/ppa
```

Error exceptions happen and the eventual message in my terminal reads:

```
error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/-team-xmbc: Not found
```

What's worse is this now brings up the graphical desktop notification:

> Sorry, the application add-apt-repository has stopped unexpectedly

I have a waveshare 7" touchscreen running their Ubuntu. I would rather run their Raspian but the soundcard and the wifi won't work on their image.

Furthermore, the wifi still won't work on their image of Ubuntu.

To begin with, has the screen I've bought managed to stop me using these basic functions? If not, how do I upload Kodi to my Pi to turn it into my media centre?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you running? You can have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/621790/cannot-remove-mistyped-repository) question. Since you are using pi I think folks at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that you have a typo in the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository pps:team-xmbc/ppa
```

The actual command is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
```

(Notice `pps:` vs `ppa:` and `xmbc` vs `xbmc`)

The notification is because of [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1453501) bug and as suggested in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621790/cannot-remove-mistyped-repository) answer you can ignore that notification.